# ReactNative: Await/Async functions wait for result before going on

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to resolve this problem, I have a function that calls two other function that will push elements inside array. My problem is that in this way the first function `function1` when it has finished calculating, it returns its value and the code continues. As soon as the second function finishes, it returns its value and the rest of the code is executed again.

What I would like to do is that the first function `function1(..)` is called as soon as it ends the second function `function2(..)` is called and when both arrays are full the code goes on. How can I do?

Thanks so much

```
async initialFunction(){

        ( async () => {
        await function1(arrayPopulated1);
        await function2(arrayPopulated2);

      
    }) ();
  // Code that use: newArray1 and newArray2  to write in the DB
}

async function1(array1){
    for(let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
    //operation there
    // value = somedata
    newArray1.push(value)
    }
}

async function1(array2){
    for(let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
    //operation there
    // value = somedata
    newArray2.push(value)
    }
}
```

EDIT:
The problem is that after `function1` finishes its value returns to `InitialFunction` continue the code of this function and write in the db. It then returns the value of `function2` to `InitialFunction` continues the code of this function and writes again to the DB.

I would like `function1` to finish its for by writing to the `newArray1` array, `function2` to write the values ​​to the `newArray2` array and when both have been populated then `InitialFunction` writes to the db.

Comment: Just call `dataReceived` function again after `timestampCheckSinistro`?

Comment: mmh Can you explain this? Did you mean that I should insert something like this.dataReceived() in timestampCheckSinistro?
The problem is that in dataReceived() I the "other Code" is a code that write in the DB

Comment: to be honest, I really didn't understand the explanation.. maybe you could try making a codepen and just mimic the database

Comment: Ok I rewrite my code to explain better (I hope) :)

Comment: Ok I edit my question using something general to understand better (maybe xD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want both promises to complete before continuing, you can wrap both of the promises in a Promise.all.

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3]).then((values) => {
  console.log(values);
});
```

[Checkout MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to wrap the promises again in another async function

```js
async initialFunction(){
   const newArray1 = [];
   const newArray2 = [];

   await function1(arrayPopulated1);
   await function2(arrayPopulated2);

   // Save to db
}

async function1(array1){
    for(let i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
        newArray1.push(value)
    }
}

async function1(array2){
    for(let i = 0; i < array2.length; i++){
        newArray2.push(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Mmh ok I'm trying this :D 
The problem is that some value of the newArray2 ( the inital values result NaN when they should be values)

Comment: You should post every code that you think will help us solve it ;)

Comment: Yes the code is this, with my code it populate two newArray but in different time. There it populates only the first.. as if not waiting for the second to write his data

Comment: From the tests carried out, it is as if the two functions went like this:
Part function1 starts populating, stops and part function2 starts populating and returns the value

Comment: Also the strange thing is that when the array is small the code works perfectly..